# Ambiguity about the confusion table: is it simply a calculation error or a technical consideration?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, pattern-recognition, tables

This table is the one from the paper entitled as: **S. Wu, T. H. Falk, W. Y. Chan, ``Automatic speech emotion recognition using modulation spectral features",  Speech Communication, vol. 53, no. 5, pp. 768-785, June 2011.** For example in Table 2, for their algorithm namely MSF, the average percentage among 7 emotions is 79.9 but it is noted here as 81.3. Also, this case are happened for other results and tables which makes this paper hard to compare with other methods.

As I want to cite this paper and compare it with our own algorithm's results for speech emotion recognition, we are in doubt to put the 79.9 or 81.3 in the table?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps not all emotions occurred with the same frequency and this is a weighted average?

Comment: @FransRodenburg: you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The per-emotion percentages reported in the table all have different denominators so you need to compute the average percentage over all emotions as the sum of the numerators over the sum of the denominators, not as the mean of the seven emotion percentages.

According to section 4.1 in the paper, the Berlin database has 127 anger speech files, 81 boredom, 46 disgust, 69 fear, 71 joy, 79 neutral, and 62 sadness. For the line that you've highlighted the number of "recognized" are deduced to be (respectively) 116, 70, 36, 49, 43, 66, and 55, which gives an average over all emotions as
$$
\frac{116 + 70 + 36 + 49 + 43 + 66 + 55}{127 + 81 + 46 + 69 + 71 + 79 + 62}=.813.
$$
In effect the overall percentage is a *weighted* average of the per-emotion percentages, as suggested in the comment by @Frans Rodenburg.

Comment: Thanks @grand_chat.  I have one question: Do you think in this paper they used monte carlo iterations for calculating the precise value (as average for some iterations) for correct classification rate or just reported the maximum value between iterations?

Comment: @Amin If I'm reading this paper correctly the authors used 10-fold cross-validation (see section 5.1). I don't see any Monte Carlo in producing the table results except in splitting the data into folds. The 'correctly recognized' rate on each emotion is based on the predictions on each held-out subset.

Comment: Thanks @grand_chat. I also think like that. But, even using 10 fold cross validation, if you put all the procedure including 10 fold cross validation into running then the result would not be the same as the previous run (I mean there may be 1 percent variance). Is it need to do the Monte Carlo in producing such tables?

Comment: @Amin I agree the authors could have done more. They could replicate this cross-validation using different random seeds, and average the results. This gives a better idea of the variability between runs. I also notice that the authors pool all speakers together when defining folds. This lack of purity in defining folds will cause some leakage (i.e., the same speaker can exist in training and in holdout), making the predictions on the holdout less honest.